# Cannot find System.Xaml in .net 6

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0

I created a console application with a target framework of .net 6.0 in order to write a custom Xaml writer. This is the project configuration:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I want to extend the `XamlXmlWriter` class but I can't import it. If I add `using System.Xaml` I get: `The type or namespace Xaml does not exist in the namespace System`. What am I missing?

Comment: You're after something, more like formization. So it is recommended to use WPF, or Winform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two changes to your project file:

- Target net6.0-windows instead of net6.0
- Add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` as an additional property

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xaml.xamlxmlwriter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), it looks like `XamlXmlWriter` is available in the Windows Desktop framework for .NET 6, but not in "general" .NET 6.

Comment: Thank you, it works. One question though, why do we also need <UseWPF>?

Comment: @danield: That brings in additional framework references, I believe. There may well be alternative, more fine-grained ways of doing so, but that's the simplest option I thought to try.